# Moving multiple listview items to new positions

Tags: algorithm

I have a listview containing `n` items. Now I'd like to move a set of items to new positions. The set of items to be moved is defined in an array containing their indices starting from `0` to `n-1`. The new position for the items is defined in such an array as well, e.g.

```
// move items at indices 2,5,11 to indices 6,1,8
oldpos = {2,5,11};
newpos = {6,1,8};
```

To move items around in the listview, I only want to use `remove()` and `insert()` methods. `remove()` removes an entry from the specified index, `insert()` inserts an entry into a specified index. Indices are 0-based like above.

What is making this complicated is the fact that as soon as I start to call `remove()` and `insert()`, listview indices will change. This is messing with my head and I'm having a hard time to find a way to deal with that. For example, in the example above, removing the item at index 2 and inserting it at index 6 will require an adaptation of the indices because the next item at index 5 will now be at index 4 because the item at index 2 has been removed etc. It's all rather difficult to think through.

Can anybody help? I'm using C but since this is an algorithmic question, answers in other languages are accepted as well as long as they don't use any advanced stuff unavailable in C.